# Get-ChildItem Where-Object -notlike $array - Is there a way to do this?

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that will recurse a specified folder and do some analysis on the files within it. I need to exclude specified sub-folders in the analysis. This list of exclusions changes dependent on the base folder being analysed. I have the script working using a long pattern like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $source_folder | 
Where-Object {
    $_.FullName -notlike "*\folder_name0\*" -and 
    $_.FullName -notlike "*\folder_name1\*" -and 
    $_.FullName -notlike "*\folder_name2\*" -and 
    $_.FullName -notlike "*\folder_name3\*" -and 
    $_.FullName -notlike "*\folder_name4\*"
}
```

but this is not very reusable. I would like to be able to store exception lists in .CSVs and call the exception list I need based on the folder set I am analyzing. What I would like to do is something like:

```
$exception_list = Import-CSV .\exception_list
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $source_folder | 
Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike $exception_list}
```

but this does not work. I suspect because I can't specify and 'and' or an 'or' between the elements in the array. I did briefly consider trying to create the whole argument on the fly using a `foreach($exception in $exception_list){$argument += "$_.FullName -notlike $exception -and"}`, but that got silly and complex pretty quickly since you still have to remove the last 'and'.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: how is the CSV file structured? is it a real CSV file or just a text file with a false CSV extension?

Comment: The csv is really irrelevant since I will be creating from whatever array I use as an exclude list. It would just be a means to store the exclude array for later use.

Comment: ah! well, then i will ignore that part of your post ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this builds an array of partial names to be excluded, and uses that array to build a regex OR for use in a `-notmatch` test.

```
$ExcludedDirList = @(
    'PSES-'
    'vscode'
    'Test_'
    )
# regex uses the pipe symbol as the logical "OR"
$RegexExcludedDirList = $ExcludedDirList -join '|'

$Results = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:TEMP -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object {
        $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $RegexExcludedDirList
        }
```

Comment: I tried this and seem to get the same results as I did with my attempt. I can include folder names like 'test' and 'imports' in the $ExcludedDirList. I see them in $RegexExcludedDirList as "imports|test" yet when I run the Get-ChildItem I still see returns from directories containing these names i.e. "E:\Storage\imports\December"

Comment: @Jeramy - i have no idea why it fails for you. [*blush*] have you checked the `$Results` $Var? on my system, that collection has NO files with those words in the directory name.

Comment: Wow, no that entirely worked, thank you! The mistake was a typo on my part.

Comment: @Jeramy - kool! glad to know you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I really like @lee_dailey's pattern of creating the regex. An alternative method could be to use `-in` or `-notin` to compare collections.

Using `Pester`:

```
It 'Filters correctly' {
    $list     = @('fileA', 'file1', 'file2', 'file32')
    $filter   = @('file1', 'file3')
    $expected = @('fileA', 'file2', 'file32')

    $list | Where-Object { $_ -notin $filter} | should -be $expected
  }
```

Or just plain comparison operators:

```
$list     = @('fileA', 'file1', 'file2', 'file32')
$filter   = @('file1', 'file3')
$expected = @('fileA', 'file2', 'file32')

$newlist = $list | Where-Object { $_ -notin $filter} 
(Compare-Object $newlist $expected).length -eq 0

> True
```